# Django SQLite testing oddity: Different path of execution?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, sqlite

This is merely a theory that I would like to figure out based on others feedback and perhaps similar experiences.

Been using mySQL for running tests, but of course an in-memory SQLite database is much faster. However, it seems to have run into some problems.

When `DATABASE_ENGINE` is set to use `django.db.backends.sqlite3` and I run `manage.py test`, the output is not as hoped:

(Removed most lines, but pointing out interesting points of failure)

```
$ python manage.py test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 12, in 
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/Users/bartekc/.virtualenvs/xx/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/bartekc/domains/xx/xx/associates/yy/models.py", line 51, in 
    class AcvTripIncentive(models.Model):

  # First interesting failure
  File "/Users/bartekc/domains/xx/xx/associates/yy/models.py", line 55, in AcvTripIncentive
    trip = models.OneToOneField(Trip, limit_choices_to={'sites' : Site.objects.get(name='ZZ'), 'is_active' : True,})

  # Next interesting failure
   File "/Users/bartekc/domains/xx/xx/associates/yyz/models.py", line 252, in 
    current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
```

There are multiple failures like this but just pointing out a couple. The problem is obvious. The Site model has no actual data, but the files contain code that try to fetch the current, or specific instances under the Site model.

Now, I can think of an easy solution: That `OneToOneField` should be switched to use a function with `limit_choices_to`, and the second one the same. The functions are then called when required, not on initial scanning of the file by Django.

**However, my actual question is: Why does this happen with SQLite and not mySQL?**. Is there a different way the two database engines process through tests? I wouldn't think so, since Python is doing all the compiling of the models.

What exactly is happening here?

Cheers.

Comment: Did you consider that the sqlite database is created newly and empty everytime you run the tests, while the mysql database might be same you use for production/development and has already some more data in it?

Comment: The mySQL database is also created a-new each time.

Comment: Where do you call Site.objects.get_current() in your model? Is it in the save() method or in a signal?

Comment: @aeby - In that example, it's called within the model, on a field declaration. I realize I can move that call into a function and pass that function as the callback for the field, which does solve the problem but the reasoning for this post is: Why does this happen with SQLite?

Comment: Need more info. Please share the full traceback. Also, what this means isn't clear to me but it makes me want to see your model: "it's called within the model, on a field declaration..."

Comment: Can you post your models and your managers and what the actual errors that you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason you are not [mocking](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) access to the database? Your UT boundary gets enormously wide when you add a database (no matter what database) to the mixture. It starts to look more like an integration test rather than a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading your Site objects from a fixture?

If so, perhaps you are stumbling upon a known issue with MySQL and transactions. Do a text search for "MySQL and Fixtures" on this page: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs

Comment: Not using fixtures for the Site object, and the problem persists only with SQLite :(